# WireGuard: how to have a persistent network card on Windows?

Tags: windows, wireguard

With OpenVPN, the virtual network card is persistent. This allow easy routing/config/whatever. This also allow TCP connections not to drop in case of VPN restart.

With WireGuard, the virtual network card is created on the fly. This is a problem with bad internet connection when WireGuard has to be restarted. For example RDP clients lose the connection frequently with smartphone tethering, some users are going crazy.

With OpenVPN everything run smoothly, so until now we keep this nice piece of software.

--> on Windows, how can I have a persistent virtual WireGuard network card?
Or a way to restart WireGuard without remove-then-create the network card?

I tried with a bridge, but Windows seems unable to keep the bridge up when any of its member is down. So the TCP connections are lost.

Comment: `This is a problem with bad internet connection when WireGuard has to be restarted` - I too use Wireguard to RDP into some systems at the office. My internet connection wasn't the best, I'd get RDP disconnects, but then RDP would just reconnect once the internet connection came back up again - I never had to restart wireguard. Surely you'd see the same dance with OpenVPN - I mean, when the internet was down, it's not like OpenVPN kept the RDP session working

Comment: "Surely you'd see the same dance with OpenVPN" So you assert I wrote nonsense. Either you are insulting me, either... no other alternative. And your answer does not bring any piece of solution.

Comment: actually was not asserting you wrote nonsense, nor was I insulting you - I'm just assuming that if you have bad internet, the type of VPN wouldn't make a difference - I know it's written poorly, but that statement starting with "surely" is actually meant to be a question - I'm sorry for any insult you chose to take